# Magento - How to check if Cross Sell products exist.

Tags: magento, view, associations, product

In view.phtml I want to check if the product has any cross sell products associated with it.

I've done the same with related products:

```
$relatedProductsId=$_product->getRelatedProductIds();
$relatedProducts=array();
 $i=0;      
foreach($relatedProductsId as $relatedProductId)
{   

    $relatedProducts[$i] =  array(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')-   >load($relatedProductId)->getProductUrl(),
                            Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($relatedProductId)->getName(),
                            Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($relatedProductId)->getImageUrl(),
                            Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($relatedProductId)->getFormat()
                            );
            $i++;
}
```

I'm not sure what the function used is for the Cross Sells products. 
Please can someone help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try

```
$crossSellProducts = $_product->getCrossSellProducts()
```

?

It will return an array of cross-sell product objects.